# Android program type already present error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've gone through several threads with the same error to find a solution (they mention duplicate package names in gradle files, duplicates in AndroidManifests and dependency version mismatches) but none are the same with my case. This is the error message I'm receiving when building the app:

```
Program type already present: ff.ecochallenges.game.BuildConfig
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: ff.ecochallenges.game.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My app gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ff.ecochallenges"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1"
    implementation project(":garden-release")
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(":game")
    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)

    // Required for instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the gradle for the new library I added (game) is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //[DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTED CODE BELOW!]
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    afterEvaluate {
        assembleDebug.finalizedBy(exportJar)
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//[DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTED CODE ABOVE!]

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
//[DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTED CODE BELOW!]
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/debug/classes.jar')
    include('classes.jar')
    into('../garden/Assets/Plugins/Android')
    rename('classes.jar', 'ecochallenges.jar')
}
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete '../garden/Assets/Plugins/Android/ecochallenges.jar'
}
exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//[DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTED CODE ABOVE!]
```

When I comment out the "implementation project(":game")" line in my app gradle it builds without error so I'm sure something's wrong with the "game" gradle but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of these lines might define `ff.ecochallenges.game` twice:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(":garden-release")
implementation project(":game")
```

would assume, that there either is a `.jar` contained in the `libs` directory

or module `garden-release` might have a dependency on module `game`.

eg. you could use `api project(":game")` in module `garden-release`.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I only run `Build->Clean Project` and problem have been solved!